# How to set a WPF image source without writing the assembly name?

Tags: .net, wpf, image, path, assemblies

Normally a WPF Image source is something like

```
WpfApplication1;component/Untitled.png
```

But what if I have to rename the assembly? I have to change all Image sources?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use relative paths:

(1). Relative to the project:

```
<Image Source="/Untitled.png".../>
```

(2). Relative to the XAML file path where this element is defined:

```
<Image Source="Untitled.png".../>
```

But, if the image is located in an external assembly then you have to specify the assembly name, otherwise there is no way WPF can find it.

Comment: But what if the image is embedded (like `Build Action = Resource`) in the same assembly?

Comment: @Jader Dias - If the image is embedded (and it is by default) relative paths will still work. You only need to specify assembly name if the image is embedded in different assembly.

Comment: Such a nice trick! I saw this question for a chance. Previously, I just used full "pack:///" specification ...

Answer (score 0):

I've written an image manager which is a custom markup extension, which has registered assemblies, and is just passed the image name, and it locates the image from the list of registered assemblies.  You could do something similar if you don't like the idea of assembly names being in the XAML markup for external assemblies.

http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wpf-tutorial-fun-with-markup-extensions is a nice starting point.